# Impact score doubled overnight. A bug?

Tags: support, people-reached

My impact score more than doubled today from around 54k to 139k.  I don't see how this could be possible.  Surely it must be a bug?

Comment: Were any of your answers moved to a high-viewcount question, but did stay eligible? Did one of your answers on a question break into the top 3 there (perhaps because one was deleted)? That might give you that much easily.

Comment: My score went up 2k in the past few days which is not abnormal. Doubt it's a bug

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/python-get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers) gives you 84k impact, I'm betting this is it. It was edited a few days ago.

Comment: @DavidG 6 months to get 54k, and then 85k because a question gets edited?  BTW, is that a moderator tool to see the viewer impact per question?

Comment: You were given an upvote on there yesterday, perhaps that caused some cache to update? No secret, I just ran a SEDE query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395423/my-impact?UserId=2411802

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yesterday you gained an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30511605/1663001). You can see this in the [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19482970/timeline). The [rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) for impact state that an answer needs the following to count:

> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - [Not self-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372469/377214) AND
>   - Also meeting one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Due to the upvote your answer met the criteria "*Score at least 5*", hence your impact jumped by a little over 84k.