# why users reached increased exponentially?

Tags: support

Yesterday my users reached total was approx. 10K.

To my pleasant surprise it jumped to 420 K, but I don't think this is correct.

What happened here? Will it be corrected?

Comment: If you interact with a question that has a lot of views it affects the views/users reached. It's a pretty poor metric really.

Comment: One of your answers to a popular question became eligible for inclusion in this metric (either it was upvoted or another answer was downvoted below yours).  You're immediately credited with having reached everyone who's ever viewed that question.  (I can't find the duplicate but this has been asked multiple times, so you're not the only one confused by that number.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I think you are looking for a comment in a chat room ;)

Comment: :-) Now I know. Thanks for the explanation. Anyone care to add an answer?

Comment: @Braiam https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316886/how-did-i-reach-so-many-people-overnight https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310676/impact-score-doubled-overnight-a-bug https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315383/did-the-impact-calculation-changed-recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11657829/792066) with its whooping 410k views, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143438/792066) which got its [score over 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) yesterday, are inflating your "people reached".

Comment: So that's pretty inaccurate right? Shouldn't "reach" people who viewed before the answer was posted (unless the answer is very old and just got its last needed UV?)